# Error in accessing address book in iOS<6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, abaddressbook, addressbookui

I have implemented method to get contacts.

For iOS 6, I used below code to get permission from the user:

```
CFErrorRef myError = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &myError);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(myAddressBook,^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
{
   if(granted)
    {
        [self GetContactInformation];
    }
   else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Contacts" message:@"You didn't permit us to access your contact details." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
});
CFRelease(myAddressBook);
```

Above code working fine in iOS 6 but below iOS 6 I am getting below error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MACROS to filter this:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 60000
CFErrorRef myError = NULL;
ABAddressBookRef myAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &myError);
ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(myAddressBook,^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
{
   if(granted)
    {
        [self GetContactInformation];
    }
   else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Contacts" message:@"You didn't permit us to access your contact details." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
});
CFRelease(myAddressBook); 
#else
    [self GetContactInformation];
#endif
```

Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you know the answer already.  Both of those functions are iOS 6+ ***only***, and do not exist in prior SDKs, meaning their symbols are undefined.  You have to code to the lowest common denominator, or up your target to iOS 6.

Comment: But for iOS6 and above I need to write that code to access contacts. I think dilip solved my problem.